# How to get ssh to use config on jump-host?

Tags: linux, ssh

Let's say I have two servers: `jump` and `target`. On `jump` I have:

`jump:~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host target
  User targetuser
  HostName actual-target-hostname.fqdn
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/target_rsa
```

... and on my client machine I want to do `ssh -J jump target`. However, this doesn't work because once the connection to `jump` is established, ssh is attempting to connect to `target` directly rather than use the properties in the `config` file above.
How do I get it to load/use that config file? I don't want to have to distribute that (large) config file to the (many, many) client machines, I'd rather just have that config defined once on the jump host.

Answer (score 0):

I had upvoted this question before I finished digging through the rest of the Internet because I have a similar issue with trying to get the proxy/bastion to use a different username for the target.  It turns out that each ssh connection/command/config option will *only* use the originating client's configuration/command/config options.

In my case, I wanted to go

```
username@local -> root@proxy -> admin@target
```

with just `ssh target`

using this config on `local`:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    User username
    ForwardAgent yes
Host proxy [proxy's IPv4]
    Hostname [proxy's FQDN]
    User root
Host target [target's IPv4]
    Hostname [target's FQDN]
    User admin
    ProxyJump proxy
```

Unfortunately, it would invariably use the wrong username and it took me a while to figure it out, because `username` exists on all three hosts.

The fix for me was to move `Host *` to the end of the config.  Apparently, I have been mistakenly thinking that later directives would override `*` and they do not

You will need to have the target's necessary config included in your client and perhaps configure agent forwarding, etc.